# AWS IoT Shadow : Can I manually try to update reported state of the shadow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I have a device that is connected to AWS IoT and it has been reporting delta for quite some time now. I am not sure but for some reason the desired and reported have not been in sync for a while and the device sends unusual number of messages containing delta when interacted with. I can see that the reported state has some left over data from previous operations and I have tried updating the desired but nothing really clears it. Can I send a updateThingShadow request with the reported state to bring them back in sync ? Is there a better way to approach this ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-shadow-data-flow.html) when designing your IoT solution using AWS IoT and shadows, you should determine the apps or devices that will request changes and those that will implement them.

In your case, you need to make your device report it's new state (changing the value for the 'Reported' field in the Shadow document) in response to the update request (which changes the value for 'Desired'). That will eliminate the delta between the values for desired and reported.

Comment: I have tried updating the desired state of the shadow expecting that it would update the reported state. It usually works but for this device it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This worked: A few attributes were present in the reported state that were missing in desired which caused a state of permanent delta as desired never updated those fields. I use update thing shadow to pass null to those extra attributes which removed them from the shadow. How those extra attributes got into reported and why they were never removed with updates to desired is still a mystery.